# AJAX request not sending validate() data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to receive the validate function output in my above PHP code. Except my AJAX, all things are working. Can anyone help me correct the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#d").click(function(){
        validate();
    })

    function validate() { 
        var x;
        var text;
        var y, senddata;

        x = document.getElementById('t').value;
        y = x.length;

        if (isNaN(x) || y < 10 || y > 10) {
            document.getElementById('t').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        // start AJAX in else case to receive validate data
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'json.php',
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'json',
                data: ({ phone: x }),
                success: function(response){
                    alert ("success !");
                },
                error: function(response){
                    alert("fail!");
                }
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: remove angular braces around the data, `data: ({phone: x}),`

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console? Otherwise, please add the relevant parts of your html document.

Comment: What is the value of x? What is the value of y? Is your else condition ever firing? If y is NOT 10, your else condition won't fire.. is that intended?

Comment: sir there is no error in console  and my php code on the same page and it does not echo ..... but ajax show  error function alert "fail"

Comment: <?php

echo json_encode($_POST);

?><body>
<input type="text" id="t">
<button id="d" >click</button>

</body>

Answer (score 0):

Need to make changes in config to set flag for CORS calls

  ...

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <!-- Enable Cross Domain AJAX calls -->
        <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Also for the AJAX to work please change the condition to go in "else" part

Comment: where it is add to change

Comment: changes needs to be done in your config file . Also if by any means you can set headers for AJAX call in PHP

Answer (score 0):

> complete with the help of **.action** in js method and without use of ajax

```
function datasend(send1,send2)
{
    senddata=send1+send2;
    document.forms["reg"].action="ajax.php?"+senddata;
    //document.forms["reg"].submit();
```

}